# Read multiple csv files stored by date from start date to end date into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a situation where my data in stored in S3 by date. So in a bucket named `mydata`, the folder `2020-01-01` contains one csv, then folder `2020-01-02` contains another csv, and so on. I want to write a function in which the user inputs a start date and end date, and the function reads all csv files between those dates and concatenates them into a single dataframe. One way I can do this is below, but this seems clunky and slow. Is there a better way?

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Define bucket, and start and end dates
bucket = 'mydata'
start_date = '2019-07-09'
end_date = '2019-07-12'

def read_data(bucket, start_date, end_date):
    # Initialize list of dataframes
    dfs = []

    # Get range of dates from which to read data
    time_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

    # Read data for each date and append to dfs
    for dte in time_range:
        d = str(dte).split(' ')[0]
        df = dd.read_csv('s3://{}/{}/*.csv'.format(bucket, d)).compute()
        dfs.append(df)

    # Concatenate dfs into one df
    merged_df = pd.concat(dfs, 0)

    return merged_df
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it,

- Create a list of Pathlib file objects
- Create a dataframe and use regex to extract a date
- Take an input of start and end date and filter the dataframe by that.
- concat a list of files based on the above filter.

Naturally, you should add in some error handling to your datetime inputs.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = '\tmp\s3\bucket\files'

df = pd.DataFrame({'files' : [f for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')],
                  'stem' : [f.stem for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')]})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stem'].str.extract('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})')[0])

print(df)

                                  files             stem       date
0  \tmp\s3\bucket\files\file-2020-04-15  file-2020-04-15 2020-04-15
1  \tmp\s3\bucket\files\file-2020-04-16  file-2020-04-16 2020-04-16
2  \tmp\s3\bucket\files\file-2020-04-17  file-2020-04-17 2020-04-17
3  \tmp\s3\bucket\files\file-2020-04-18  file-2020-04-18 2020-04-18
4  \tmp\s3\bucket\files\file-2020-04-19  file-2020-04-19 2020-04-19
```

---

```
start_date = input('Enter your Start Date')
end_date = input('Enter your End Date')
```

assuming these dates are the `'2020-04-15'` and `'2020-04-16'` we can return a list based of that range

## Concatenate DataFrame.

```
file_date_slice = df.set_index('date').loc[start_date:end_date]['files'].tolist()


concat_df = pd.concat([dd.read_csv(f).compute() for f in file_date_slice])
```